# vtkWidget position on multiple renderers

Tags: vtk

I am running into a relative simple problem for days, and I didn't find any solving: I have a vtkRenderWindow where I spread up 4 renderers, but on runtime I hide 3 of them, so I could have 1 or 4 renderers at the time ...

On renderer 1 I intend to put a vtkSliderWidget ... to achieve that, I wrote:

```
        vtkSliderRepresentation2D* pSliderRep = vtkSliderRepresentation2D::New();
......
......
        pSliderRep->GetPoint1Coordinate()->SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedViewport();
        pSliderRep->GetPoint1Coordinate()->SetValue(0.1, 0.1);
        pSliderRep->GetPoint2Coordinate()->SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedViewport();
        pSliderRep->GetPoint2Coordinate()->SetValue(0.9, 0.1);
        m_pSlider->SetInteractor(m_pInteractor);
        m_pSlider->SetRepresentation(pSliderRep);
```

where **m_pSlider** is a **vtkSliderWidget** object ...

the problem become where I have 4 renderers:

```
Renderer 1    Renderer 2
Renderer 3    Renderer 4
```

in this stage, the widget I found over renderer 3, not over renderer 1 where is belong ... why ?

Is there something that I am doing wrong ? I dig in for this issue for days !! Can you help me ?

Later edit:

I made a simple test using [this test project](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/MultipleViewports):

```
int main(int, char *[])
{
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();

renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

vtkRenderer* renderer[4];

// Define viewport ranges
double xmins[4] = {0, .5, 0, .5};
double xmaxs[4] = {0.5, 1, 0.5, 1};
double ymins[4] = {0, 0, .5, .5};
double ymaxs[4] = {0.5, 0.5, 1, 1};
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    renderer[i] = vtkRenderer::New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer[i]);
    CString sTemp;
    sTemp.Format("%.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f\n", xmins[i], ymins[i], xmaxs[i], ymaxs[i]);
    renderer[i]->SetViewport(xmins[i], ymins[i], xmaxs[i], ymaxs[i]);
    // Create a sphere
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource = 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();
    sphereSource->SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    sphereSource->SetRadius(5);
    sphereSource->Update();
    // Create a mapper and actor
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(sphereSource->GetOutputPort());
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);
    renderer[i]->AddActor(actor);
    renderer[i]->ResetCamera();
    renderWindow->Render();
    renderWindow->SetWindowName(_T("Multiple ViewPorts"));
}

vtkSliderRepresentation2D* pSliderRep = vtkSliderRepresentation2D::New();
pSliderRep->SetMinimumValue(3.0);
pSliderRep->SetMaximumValue(20.0);
pSliderRep->SetPlaceFactor(1);
pSliderRep->GetSliderProperty()->SetColor(0.65, 0.75, 0.90);
pSliderRep->GetTitleProperty()->SetColor(1, 0, 0);
pSliderRep->SetLabelFormat(_T("%.2g"));
pSliderRep->GetLabelProperty()->SetColor(1, 0, 0);
pSliderRep->GetSelectedProperty()->SetColor(0, 1, 0);
pSliderRep->GetTubeProperty()->SetColor(0.36, 0.5, 0.66);
pSliderRep->GetTubeProperty()->SetDisplayLocationToForeground();
pSliderRep->GetCapProperty()->SetColor(0.36, 0.5, 0.66);
pSliderRep->SetEndCapLength(0);
pSliderRep->SetEndCapWidth(0.025);
pSliderRep->SetSliderWidth(0.025);
pSliderRep->SetSliderLength(0.045);
pSliderRep->SetHandleSize(6);
pSliderRep->SetTubeWidth(0.032);

pSliderRep->GetPoint1Coordinate()->SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedDisplay();
pSliderRep->GetPoint1Coordinate()->SetValue(0.01, 0.99);
pSliderRep->GetPoint2Coordinate()->SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedDisplay();
pSliderRep->GetPoint2Coordinate()->SetValue(0.99, 0.99);

vtkSliderWidget* pSlider = vtkSliderWidget::New();
pSlider->SetInteractor(renderWindowInteractor);
pSlider->SetCurrentRenderer(renderer[0]);
pSlider->SetRepresentation(pSliderRep);
pSlider->EnabledOn();
pSlider->SetDefaultRenderer(renderer[0]);
pSlider->SetAnimationModeToAnimate();

renderWindowInteractor->Start();

pSliderRep->Delete();
pSlider->Delete();

for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    renderer[i]->Delete();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I see no slider ... what I have done wrong ?

[New data] In fact, the problem is reduced on setting up the slider on other renderer than renderer 0:

```
int main(int, char *[])
{
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();

renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

vtkRenderer* renderer[4];

// Define viewport ranges
double xmins[4] = {0, .5, 0, .5};
double xmaxs[4] = {0.5, 1, 0.5, 1};
double ymins[4] = {0, 0, .5, .5};
double ymaxs[4] = {0.5, 0.5, 1, 1};
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    renderer[i] = vtkRenderer::New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer[i]);
    CString sTemp;
    sTemp.Format("%.1f, %.1f, %.1f, %.1f\n", xmins[i], ymins[i], xmaxs[i], ymaxs[i]);
    renderer[i]->SetViewport(xmins[i], ymins[i], xmaxs[i], ymaxs[i]);
    // Create a sphere
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource> sphereSource = 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkSphereSource>::New();
    sphereSource->SetCenter(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    sphereSource->SetRadius(5);
    sphereSource->Update();
    // Create a mapper and actor
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = 
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(sphereSource->GetOutputPort());
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);
    renderer[i]->AddActor(actor);
    renderer[i]->ResetCamera();
    renderWindow->Render();
    renderWindow->SetWindowName(_T("Multiple ViewPorts"));
}

vtkSliderRepresentation2D* pSliderRep = vtkSliderRepresentation2D::New();
pSliderRep->SetMinimumValue(3.0);
pSliderRep->SetMaximumValue(20.0);

pSliderRep->GetPoint1Coordinate()->SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedViewport();
pSliderRep->GetPoint1Coordinate()->SetValue(0.1, 0.9);
pSliderRep->GetPoint2Coordinate()->SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedViewport();
pSliderRep->GetPoint2Coordinate()->SetValue(0.9, 0.9);

vtkSliderWidget* pSlider = vtkSliderWidget::New();
pSlider->SetInteractor(renderWindowInteractor);
pSlider->SetCurrentRenderer(renderer[1]);    // <-- not working !!!
pSlider->SetDefaultRenderer(renderer[1]);    // <-- not working !!!
pSlider->SetAnimationModeToAnimate();

pSlider->SetRepresentation(pSliderRep);
pSlider->EnabledOn();

pSliderRep->Modified();

renderWindowInteractor->Start();

pSliderRep->Delete();
pSlider->Delete();

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    renderer[i]->Delete();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

the question is, how can I show the slider on renderer 1 (or 2, or 3), but on renderer 0 ?

Might be something simple ...

Answer (score 1):

After applying the representation and all the stuff call `CreateDefaultRepresentation()` - this should change a lot.

```
pSlider->SetRepresentation(pSliderRep);
pSlider->EnabledOn();
pSlider->CreateDefaultRepresentation();
```

Comment: I teste what you said ... by now didn't worked (perhaps I done something wrong) ... but I will try tomorrow and I will keep you online ... I did not believe that is so hard to setup a slider on renderer 1, 2, or 3 ... :( However, kindly thank you for your attention !

Comment: I tried it with a similar setup like you and run in to the same problem, until i called `CreateDefaultRepresentation()` - the other problem could be the camera. Probably the slider is displayed somewhere in the space. Truly a very strange behavior sometimes....